# App icon unassigned image compilation warning message

Tags: ios, xcode6, xcode7

I've tried googling this but am still non the wiser as to what the actual problem or solution is.
I supplied all the app icon images Xcode was asking for but I'm getting an AppIcon unassigned image compilation message. 
What do I need to do to remove the warning essage?

[image]

Comment: is it Xcode6 with iOS8 SDK? I have a little doubt about it... can you confirm it, please?

Comment: Yes its Xcode 6 beta 6 and iOS8.Ialso  get a similar message about the launch image as well as for the app icon.

Comment: something is quite not correct on your screenshot, the labels (at least!) should say _...iOS7-8_ or _...iOS5-8_, and the iOS8 _3x_ icon is missing (_unassigned_ in your screenshot). it seems something happens to your iOS8 SDK because your Xcode does not recognise it, but up to iOS7 only. are you sure this is Xcode6 and not an Xcode5 which cannot _recognise_ the new assets?

Comment: I'll try re-installing Xcode/SDK and see if it fixes anything

Answer (score 15):

I faced same problem with XCode7 and app icon image, and just Selecting the unassigned asset and pressing delete solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

If you go into the media.xcassets directory in finder you can edit the contents.json file to remove anything without "filename" assigned. For example you would remove:

```
{
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "unassigned" : true
 }
```

And that should remove the compiler warnings.

Comment: Since originally posting I've somehow managed to get the app icon warnings to be removed however I still have them for the launch images and for those there isn't a contents.json file. There are two subfolders, within AppIcon.appiconset there is a Contents.json but within LaunchImage.launchimage there isn't a Contents.json.

Comment: Hmm I wonder if the lack of a contents.json may be causing your issue. In XCode6 I just created a new project then created a new launch image. Within that it had a contents.json. Did you try creating a new launch image and placing the current photos in that?

Comment: I don't see anything that says "unassigned" in any of my contents.json file

Comment: @softwareisfun I would assume that you're running a newer version of xcode so this answer would not apply.

Answer (score 2):

In my case a created Forms based project auto generates a project structure that refers to an app icon for the "Car" iOS app category:
/Users/your_userid/Projects/ProjectName/iOS/Resources/Images.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/Contents.json

I opened that json file and removed the app icon entry that contained an "idiom" entry of "Car".
Then the build was successful.  Another solution would have been to add an app icon for Car. But my app is not going to be used in a car.

Answer (score 0):

I created the project from Xcode 5 version ,when i build, i received 5 unassigned images... warnings and when i import it into the xcode 7 version , i just received 1 warning, then i delete the unassigned image and build , now all warning removed.